# Fetch In-App Purchase Product List ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, in-app-purchase, storekit

I've actually did research about Apple inApp Purchase and wanted to integrate it to my app.

Here is what I've found so far and I still got a few questions that wanted to seek for help which I couldn't really get the answer up to now.

First, I've found the way to submit my items to itunesconnect and ask for review.
Second, I've found the way to create a test account in order to test out the purchases.

Question I wanted to ask is,

For now, I couldn't obtain any products from Apple is because of my items are yet to be approve by Apple along with my first version of app.

So I've tried to use this codes to request the products that I've submit earlier.

```
- (void)requestProductData
{
    NSSet *productList = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"com.simplesdk.stage1", @"com.simplesdk.stage2" nil];

    SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productList];
    request.delegate = (id)self;
    [request start];
}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    self.storeProducts = [NSArray arrayWithArray:response.products];

    NSLog(@"self.storeProducts.found: %d", [self.storeProducts count]);
}
```

So basically, for the codes above the log actually returning 0 result which represented I could not get any items from Apple.

*Note: I've created the app and items in itunesconnect but the app are still in development stage which I hope there is a way for me to actually tested out the transaction before I submit it. Thanks!

p/s: I've also enable the in-app purchase for my development provisioning profile.

Comment: your code looks fine if everything else is setup correctly and if you have just created the product ids, just hold on for 4-5 hrs and retry.

Comment: @samfisher thanks for your reply. So do you mean it is fine also if my products are in "Ready to Submit" status?

Comment: If you haven't done already you may want to read [Technical Note TN2259 - Adding In-App Purchase to your iOS and Mac Applications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2259/_index.html)

Comment: @MatthiasBauch thanks for the reply. Will follow the guides and see how again ya! Thanks a lot!

Comment: yes, if the products are in "Ready to Submit", then also it works in sandbox environment

Comment: If you're running iOS5 there seems to be a problem with the Sandbox environment at the moment - my previously working code is getting no products returned, but it's fine on iOS6.

Comment: @KeithYeoh have you got any solution? i am also facing same problem

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good tutorial for in app purchase:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial 
I hope it will help you...